# What the "case" refers to?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I have this sentence:

> For example, “page navigation bar” at the end of the “results” section is a **suitable element** for this purpose.

To make it more general, could I use "case" instead of "element"? Specially with regard to the collocations of suitable.

> For example, “page navigation bar” at the end of the “results” section is a **suitable case** for this purpose.

The following sentence also seems to be an option:

> For example, “page navigation bar” at the end of the “results” section is a candidate for this purpose.

"things", "objects", "items" are things we use to call objects in abstract.

What is the usage of "cases"? Could it be used in the same category above?

---

by "page navigation bar" I mean this

[image]

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is that "element" is a good "Web" word. HTML elements, page elements etc.

Comment: @JMB True, its a good technical term. but suppose that I address a common user which only see the Webpage as its surface layer.

Comment: Seems fine then. Use for variety.

Comment: By 'element', are you referring to just the page navigation bar or are you referring to the situation of having the bar at the end of the results section? Could you expand on your example, as I think a wider context would help.

Comment: @SteveIves I inserted a picture of it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

An element is usually a 'thing' that can be identified; a 'case' is an abstract situation (unless you are using case to refer to a bag or holdall). E.g

> "The page navigation bar element may be at the end of the results
>   section. In that case, it would be suitable for this purpose."

Here, 'case' is referring to the placing of the bar and the section; it is not referring to a single item.

Comment: Then you mean 'case' is not proper for my purpose. Then I should use 'element' or 'item', I think. You could offer a alternative word if there is.

Comment: @Ahmad - in that case :-) I would use 'element' as that appears to be the usual term for items in a UI (user interface).

Comment: Your right, however, regarding the collocations of suitable I came up with "suitable candidate for this purpose"

Comment: 'Candidate' works, but gives the impression that there are various 'elements' you could choose from and this is one of them, but you have not yet decided (it's only a candidate, it's not necessarily the one you will use). 'Preferred candidate' would imply that there were several possibilities and that this one is the best'.

Comment: That's true, there are  several possibilities for the purpose.